# React, not able to not run the logic inside useEffect after url change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this in my component:

```
const [filtersFetched, setFiltersFetched] = React.useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  if (history.location.search.includes("publisher_id=") && !filtersFetched) {
    fetchAllAxiosResponse <
      API.Publisher >
      (CatalogService.getPublishers, new URLSearchParams(), 1500)
        .then((data) => {
          setPublishers(data);
          setFiltersFetched(true);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setFiltersFetched(true);
        });
  }
}, [filtersFetched, history.location]);

const asyncFilters = {
  publisher_id: filtersFetched,
};
```

The idea is that the `useEFfect` runs every time that the history stack changes, but if it has already been run once, it should not run again. Hence the !`filtersFetched` in the first condition

How can I avoid that? Because every time I change the location (I'm replacing the url in other part of the app), `filtersFetched` is reset to `false`, and the whole fetch happens again.

Comment: How do you replace the url ?

Comment: @Dilshan history.replace({ search: newParams.toString() });

Comment: It seems like your component unmount when query strings change due to the way you design your component tree. Create a context and put the above logic in a context provider and use it in a higher level of your code.

Comment: Or if you can add the route configuration and the way you used the above component, others will able to give u a proper answer

Answer (score 1):

Thats's happening because whenever you change the url, the component gets unmounted. And when you come back, it's a fresh component, which means `filtersFetched` state will be at its initial value. I assume you declared it like this:

```
const [filtersFetched, setFiltersFetched] = useState(false);
```

That's the normal behaviour in React. If it's really important for you that it shouldn't run on mount after url change, you could use `localStorage` to remember the value of `filtersFetched`. For that change your `useEffect` to:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (history.location.search.includes("publisher_id=") && !filtersFetched) {
    fetchAllAxiosResponse <
      API.Publisher >
      (CatalogService.getPublishers, new URLSearchParams(), 1500)
        .then((data) => {
          setPublishers(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          setFiltersFetched(true);
          localStorage.setItem("filtersFetched", JSON.stringify(true));
        });
  }
}, [filtersFetched, history.location]);
```

And set the initial value of `filtersFetched` like below instead of what you had before:

```
const initialFiltersFetchedValue = localStorage.getItem("filtersFetched")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("filtersFetched"))
  : false;
const [filtersFetched, setFiltersFetched] = useState(initialFiltersFetchedValue);
```

Or as @Dilshan said, you could use a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) that wraps your app, in which you would put the above logic. Also you could use a library like [React Query](https://react-query.tanstack.com) to cache your HTTP requests.